# See which context is used on a page when looking at the page

Tags: 7

When you are watching a page, is there a quick way for seeing all of the contexts that are being applied? Ideally I would like to be able to see which context is responsible per the blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the active context api to get this done.,

```
$contexts = context_active_contexts();
print_r (array_keys($contexts));
```

Place the above code in your form_alter or in any hook_node_view. This will list the active context in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module as suggested in the previous answer, there is also the [Devel Catcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_catcher) module (which has [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) as a module dependency).

Here is an excerpt from its project page (why you may want to consider this module):

> ... aggregates or "catches" all development debug info into one easy to access place.
>
> Similar in style to Firebug or Chrome's Inspector. Devel Catcher intercepts common debug info into a tabbed interface as opposed to having to assign debug blocks to a region or dumping the output at the end of your HTML document.
>
> Currently Devel Catcher can catch the query log from the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, node access rules from the Devel Node Access module and the context inspector block from the Context UI module.

Another way to look at this: it enhances your "debugging" experience (hm, hm ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled it provides a block called "Context Inspector" which you need only place in a region on your page in order to see the current contexts output via Krumho.